# How can I create / populate a global model in Angular before controllers and directives are loaded?

Tags: angularjs

I don't know if this is a good practice or not, but I would like to have a model object that is global over my whole Angular site.

I can use `angular.constant` to store my global model object, however the data I want to populate comes from backend, hence an HTTP request is required in order to populate it with relevant data.

Currently, I populate this global model at `angular.run`, however `angular.run` is actually executed after controllers and directives are loaded, so if a directive requires data from the global model, it fails.

Is there a better place where I can bootstrap the data population before any directives or controllers activate? and/or a way I can delay the activation of controllers and directives, until my HTTP request is finished somehow?

Any ideas or advice on this subject would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you want to directives/controllers to wait until this global model is resolved? If no, it doesnt matter when it runs before or after controllers since it is async.

Comment: Yea, that would be awesome to delay the directives/controllers until my bootstrap is done. If that is even possible somehow in Angular.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what `ui-router` resolutions are for. If you are using angulars default routing system throw that out and use `ui-router` (seriously this is what everyone uses).

When you are defining your states you want to create a resolution for your root state. The resolution must be resolved before the state itself if loaded.

```
$stateProvider.state('app', {
  resolve: {
    user: function($stateParams, $http) {
      return $http.get('/users/' + $stateParams.userId);
    }
  }
}).state('app.userProfile', {}); // Can't enter this state until the parent resolutions are resolved.
```

When you use resolutions they are available as injectables in your controllers. So if your `app.userProfile` state uses the user object it will be available as an injectable when that controller is instantiated.

```
app.controller('UserProfileController', function($scope, user) {
  $scope.user = user; // Pretty cool!
});
```

Resolutions are pretty flexible. You can have resolutions waiting on other resolutions.

```
$stateProvider.state('app.userProfile.posts', {
  resolve: {
     threads: function($http) {
       return $http.get('users/' + $stateParams.userId + '/threads');
     },
     posts: function(threads, $http) {
       // Threads has to resolve before this resolution starts
     }
  }
});
```

Resolutions can return a value immediately or use a promise. If a promise is used, the state transition will wait until it is resolved before instantiating the controller.

Hope this is what you're looking for!

Comment: I'm not using any routing at all though.

Comment: I think you'l need some system of loading your views without the default angular process if that makes sense. I would still suggest using this even if your "routing" only has one state.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best way, but if you are kinda new to angular and don't want to get into routing right away... you can set up a `$watch` on the global model, inside your controller, so after `angular.run` is executed, you will get a callback where you can process the available data.

something like

```
$scope.$watch(variable, function(){
//process
});
```

where variable is the scope variable which finally gets populated with the data (probably in `$http.success`)

Comment: Yea, this is what I currently do, but on the rootscope.